# How to test this code with RSpec 3.5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I nedd to test this code. Its inside of a application_helper in my rails app.

```
def greet
  now = Time.now
  today = Date.today.to_time

  morning = today.beginning_of_day
  noon = today.noon
  evening = today.change( hour: 17 )
  night = today.change( hour: 20 )
  tomorrow = today.tomorrow

  if (morning..noon).cover? now
    'Good Morning'
  elsif (noon..evening).cover? now
    'Good Afternoon'
  elsif (evening..night).cover? now
    'Good Evening'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) gem to test time-based code. For documentation on testing helpers in general, see the [RSpec documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/helper-specs/helper-spec).

You could write something like this:

```
RSpec.describe ApplicationHelper, type: :helper do
  describe '#greet' do
    subject { helper.greet }

    context 'in the morning' do
      around do |example|
        Timecop.travel(Time.now.change(hour: 2), &example)
      end

      it { is_expected.to eq('Good Morning') }
    end
  end
end
```

What is happening here is that the `around` block will invoke timecop to "travel back in time" (i.e. simulate a specific time), run the example and return back to regular behaviour afterwards. When using Timecop, you need to make sure that you don't forget to return to the original time, so using `around` blocks is recommended.